# Using joinattributesbylocation in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I want to join the attributes of two layers but only want to keep the objects of my input layer. So I came across the function "joinattributesbylocation" and tried to add it in my script like this:

```
alg_params = {
    'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
    'INPUT': tmp_repair_wea ['OUTPUT'],
    'JOIN': tmp_repair_analysis ['OUTPUT'],
    'JOIN_FIELDS': [''],
    'METHOD': 0,  
    'PREDICATE': [0],
    'PREFIX': '',
    'OUTPUT': path_wea
}
processing.run('native:joinattributesbylocation', alg_params)
```

When i do it like this i get an empty layer. I thought maybe QGIS 3.2 has a problem with the input layer being a pointlayer and the layer to join is a polygon layer but when I tried to do it manually it worked just fine. And when I count the features after running the algorithm it still counts 253 features as it is supposed to but as soon as I want to save it I get an empty layer.

What might the problem be?

Comment: Have you made sure it is valid? `yourlayer.isValid()`

Comment: Yes the input and join layer as well as the output layer is valid

Comment: Could you share more line in your script? We don't know about `tmp_repair_wea `, `tmp_repair_analysis ` and `path_wea`.